# Ubuntu 20.04 Sever unable to connect to WIFI

Tags: server, wireless, 20.04, internet

I am new to working with servers and just installed Ubuntu 20.04 Sever onto my Lenovo laptop. Throughout the initial set up, I did not connect to the internet. I read that I could do that within the terminal later. Though I cannot `ifconfig` or do any other commands because I do not have the necessary tools installed. But, I cannot install them because I am not connected to the internet. So I am not sure how to connect to the internet via wirelessly and escape this infinite loop?

Any suggestions?

**Edits**

input: `sudo lshw -C network`

Output:

```
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    production: Wireless 3160
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
    logical name: wlp8s0
    version: 93
    serial: a0:88:69:77:f6:32
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration; broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firemware=17.3216344376.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:38 memory:d1600000-d1601fff
*-network DISABLED
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
    logical name: enp9s0
    version: 10
    serial: f8:a9:63:2a:94:b9
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
    resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1504000-d1504fff memory:d1500000-d1503fff
```

Input: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Output:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets: {}
  version: 2
```

Comment: I am sure you have tried this but if you have an ethernet cable and access to your router all of this will work. Otherwise you can do all of it with the nmcli Network Manager Command Line INterface https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html

Comment: I receive: `Command "nmcli" not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install network-manager'. Again, I can't install because I am not connected.

Comment: Do you have ethernet cable to router/modem, to install the software required to use wireless? Wireless access is not supplied standard in Server. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @walttheboss This is a netplan environment, not NetworkManager.

Comment: @Zman3 Don't even think about installing NetworkManager. You'll need to use netplan. If you can cable an ethernet cable to your router/modem, I can write you the required .yaml files to make this work.

Comment: @heynnema I do have a Ethernet cable. Do you want me to connect that to my laptop and router and then do the following commands you have written above?

Comment: @heynnema Also, with those commands above, is there any information that I should leave out for the safety of my network (so that others can't use it to get to my personal stuff - hackers)?

Comment: @Zman3 Yes, depending on what, if any, .yaml file got created during the install, there may be a password, or MAC address, that you've got to xxxxx out. Connecting the ethernet cable may, or may not, get you Internet access, again depending on the current .yaml file. See what you can get and report back. And yes, please do those commands for me. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I have made the edits above. I do not believe any other this information should be xxxxx out. I will be gone this weekend, so wont be back on until Sunday evening.

Comment: I'll write an answer with a .yaml for you to use, and further instructions.

Comment: @Zman3 Status please...

Comment: @Zman3 Status please...

Comment: @heynnema So sorry, I ended up starting another project and just got around to doing this. It worked. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the existing .yaml in /etc/netplan with this... keep the exact spacing, indentation, and no tabs... fill in the SSID and password...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp8s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Connect to Internet via ethernet cable.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`

`reboot`

Disconnect ethernet cable.

Connect via wireless.